# Create a link to another directory based on the current URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

My visitor is on a page with a URL like this:

`https://example.com/dir1/foo/page.php?a=search&cid=&topicId=11&q=`

I want to display a link on the page that, when clicked, will redirect them to another directory, but everything else about the URL will remain the same:

`https://example.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/foo/page.php?a=search&cid=&topicId=11&q=`

It seems to me that a guy could use something like this...

`window.location.href;`

...and then replace `dir1/` with `dir1/dir2/dir3/`. But this is way over my head.

Comment: `location.href = location.href.replace("dir1", "dir1/dir2/dir3")`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @freedomn-mn

I ended up with this working solution:

`<a id="new-url" onclick="location.href = location.href.replace('/dir1', '/dir1/dir2/dir3')">`